# Why is .active() not working with typehead

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, typeahead

We are using [typehead](http://plugins.jquery.com/typeahead.js/) for autocomplete with bootstrap 2.3, [bootstrap-typeahead.js](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead). Though typeahead is a jQuery plugin, `jQuery.active` is always `0` even when it is trying to get suggestions from server.

Does `jQuery.active` working only for jQuery ajax requests? Is there any alternative to `jQuery.active` if I use any plugins rather than `jQuery.ajax` to get information from server.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this ?

Comment: . active only gets updated when jquery.ajaxstart method is called so if you aren't using jquery's ajax methods active won't update.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but from the code on github it appears to me that this is the function responsible for retrieving and returning the data.  It is found in the dropdown.js file of the plugin.

```
getDatumForSuggestion: function getDatumForSuggestion($el) {
      var datum = null;

      if ($el.length) {
        datum = {
          raw: Dataset.extractDatum($el),
          value: Dataset.extractValue($el),
          datasetName: Dataset.extractDatasetName($el)
        };
      }

      return datum;
    }
```

give that is the case you could probably utilize jquery's .active method to get you when the data is being extracted and when its been returned by modifying this function like so,

```
getDatumForSuggestion: function getDatumForSuggestion($el) {
      var datum = null;

      $.active++ 

      if ($el.length) {
        datum = {
          raw: Dataset.extractDatum($el),
          value: Dataset.extractValue($el),
          datasetName: Dataset.extractDatasetName($el)
        };
      }

      $.active--
      return datum;
    }
```

Personally, I wouldn't suggest using $.active but creating your own global variable for this specific purpose.  The reason why is you can't always be sure, especially if you're using jquery plugins, when you might actually be calling a jQuery.ajax method and active will update at that time, perhaps not giving you what you're looking for, unless you are wanting to see other connections to the server along with this plugin, in which case use `$.active`

Comment: thats great but is there any generic way i can find out all the pending connections. document.readyState is also working which was written in some answers to tell pending status of the browser.